# Create Temporary Table For Testing Unmanged Model in Django

Tags: django, testing, django-models, django-testing, factory-boy

I've got a django app that has a couple models that read from tables in an unmanaged database.

I'm just trying to create tests appropriately to make sure that the application can be as well tested as possible. I'm using factory_boy to assist with the creation of test data.

One of my unmanaged models looks like this:

```
class EmpGroup(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='id', primary_key=True)
    staff_group = models.ForeignKey(
        StaffGroup,
        db_column='staff_group_id',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        db_column='user_id',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    location = models.ForeignKey(
        Location,
        db_column='base_loc',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    location_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.last_name}, {self.first_name}'

    class Meta(object):
        managed = getattr(settings, 'UNDER_TEST', False)
        db_table = 'control_v_empGroup'
```

Because that model is unmanaged - there is no migration to tell it to create the table `control_v_empGroup` when setting up the test DB's. So when I run my tests - I get the the error that the table doesn't exist!

My EmpGroupFactory looks like this:

```
class EmpGroupFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.EmpGroup

    id = 1
    staff_group = factory.SubFactory(StaffGroupFactory)
    user = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)
    location = factory.SubFactory(LocationFactory)
    first_name = 'Test'
    last_name = 'Grp'
    location_name = 'Test'
```

In my settings I have this:

```
UNDER_TEST = (len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'test')
if UNDER_TEST:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'default-db.sqlite3'),
        },
        'camp': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'camp-db.sqlite3'),
        },
    }
else:
    DATABASES =
    # actual dbs for regular use
```

I setup the `UNDER_TEST` so that I can differentiate the databases at test time, from the regular databases in non-text examples. Testing databases are SQLlite.

Is there a way to force Django to setup a table for that particular model when testing, but not during other times?

What is the best way to get unmanaged models under test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `Pytest-Django` as that testing framework actually allows for doing exactly what I wanted.

Using the `--nomigrations` flag, it takes my models which are only managed by django in tests and creates the appropriate table name for them in the test database. Then I can use `factory_boy` to create mock data and test it up!